# I need to select all columns in a table for records that meet multiple specific parameters

Tags: mysql, max, mysql-5.6

I am using Navicat MySQL as my client, with MySQL 5.6. Consider the following imaginary user changelog table we'll call **[user_changelog]**.

| user_id | field | old_value | new_value | date | username |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2133 | Address | 101 Main Street | 202 Duo Lane | 2021-05-06 | User1 |
| 2133 | City | Townsville | Cityburb | 2021-05-06 | User1 |
| 2133 | State | AL | CA | 2021-05-06 | User1 |
| 2133 | ZIP | 12334 | 90210 | 2021-05-06 | User1 |
| 2133 | Max Orders | 10 | 15 | 2021-05-06 | Manager1 |
| 1100 | State | TX | MD | 2021-04-30 | User1 |
| 1100 | Company Name | LameCo | CoolCo | 2021-04-30 | User1 |
| 2133 | Max Orders | NULL | 10 | 2021-04-25 | User1 |
| 1100 | Max Orders | NULL | 10 | 2021-04-14 | Manager2 |

From this table, I need return only the rows for the most recent change to a specific data point across all users. For example, the most recent change to the Max Orders value for each unique user, sorted in DESC order by date of change.

My expected returned data set from the [user_changelog] table should be:

| user_id | field | old_value | new_value | date | username |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2133 | Max Orders | 10 | 15 | 2021-05-06 | Manager1 |
| 1100 | Max Orders | NULL | 10 | 2021-04-14 | Manager2 |

This query returns the most recent 500 changes to the **Max Orders** value:

```
SELECT
        cl.user_id
    ,   cl.field
    ,   cl.old_value
    ,   cl.new_value
    ,   cl.date
    ,   cl.username
                        
FROM user_changelog     AS  cl

WHERE cl.field = 'Max Orders'

ORDER BY cl.date DESC
LIMIT 500
```

...but if I try to limit the results by modifying `cl.date` to `MAX(cl.date)` in the SELECT statement, I of course get only a single row with the most recent `date` value, which I understand, but the other returned columns aren't even from the same record.

I understand I need to use a sub-query here. But I'm struggling with that. I've tried this substitute WHERE clause for the above query, but it seems to run forever and never returns a result:

```
WHERE cl.date = (SELECT MAX(d1.date) FROM user_changelog AS d1 WHERE d1.user_id = cl.user_id)
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong at this point. TIA for any help!

V/R
Paul